# Nuxt not loading nested component

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I've created a third party components library as described on this page https://nuxtjs.org/blog/improve-your-developer-experience-with-nuxt-components#third-party-component-library. Than I used the components in a new clean nuxt project. I have a `BaseCard` component which has 3 slots and I have a `BaseImage` component. Now I want to use the `BaseImage` component in a slot from the `BaseCard` component but it is not rendered. If I add an additional `BaseImage` component outside of the `BaseCard` component, than all `BaseImage` components are rendered (see screenshots below). Seems like that the components within a slot are not loaded.

**Screenshots**

without additional `BaseImage`
[image]

with additional `BaseImage`
[image]

**Code**

Don't work

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <BaseCard>
        <template v-slot:image>
            <BaseImage
                imgSrc="https://picsum.photos/400/400?random=1"
                imgAlt="Some alt tag"
            />
        </template>
        <template v-slot:header>
            Here might be a page title
        </template>
        <template v-slot:content>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum
                pariatur distinctio cum. Ratione doloribus asperiores eaque
                laboriosam repellendus perferendis iusto magni in necessitatibus
                exercitationem eum expedita aliquam autem, tenetur itaque.
            </p>
        </template>
    </BaseCard>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";

export default Vue.extend({});
</script>
```

works

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <BaseCard>
        <template v-slot:image>
            <BaseImage
                imgSrc="https://picsum.photos/400/400?random=1"
                imgAlt="Some alt tag"
            />
        </template>
        <template v-slot:header>
            Here might be a page title
        </template>
        <template v-slot:content>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum
                pariatur distinctio cum. Ratione doloribus asperiores eaque
                laboriosam repellendus perferendis iusto magni in necessitatibus
                exercitationem eum expedita aliquam autem, tenetur itaque.
            </p>
        </template>
    </BaseCard>
    <BaseImage
       imgSrc="https://picsum.photos/400/400?random=1"
       imgAlt="Some alt tag"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";

export default Vue.extend({});
</script>
```

nuxt.config.js (`shared-components` is my library for the components)

```js
export default {
  // Target: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-target
  target: "static",

  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    title: "demo",
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: "en",
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: "utf-8" },
      { name: "viewport", content: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1" },
      { hid: "description", name: "description", content: "" },
    ],
    link: [{ rel: "icon", type: "image/x-icon", href: "/favicon.ico" }],
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: ["@/assets/scss/variables.scss"],
  styleResources: {
    scss: ["./assets/scss/*.scss"],
  },

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/typescript
    "@nuxt/typescript-build",
    "shared-components",
  ],

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: ["@nuxtjs/style-resources"],

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {},
};
```

I use nuxt 2.15.2.

Comment: could be a render error because it cannot find  ```imageStyle.BORDERD```

Comment: Are you sure the slot 'image' is available?

Comment: @Talal I think if the image source isn't correct then the "alt" text is going to be displayed, which he might have noticed in the first place, still better you asked to be on the safer side and be more sure.

Comment: `imageStyle.BORDERD` is not the issue and the card component has the image slot. As i mentioned, it works if I load an additional BaseImage outside of the BaseCard component

Comment: its because i replicated the components and i got a render error ```imageStyle.BORDERD``` removed it and the components rendered as expected

Comment: Try to make a reproduction on codepen or codesandbox. 90% of a time you find solution yourself doing it. If not it is easier to help. Now it is more guessing as we don't see more code.

Comment: i already made it https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-browser-noyx5?file=/pages/index.vue

Comment: If i have the components in my project it works fine but my components are located in a npm package (https://nuxtjs.org/blog/improve-your-developer-experience-with-nuxt-components#third-party-component-library)